# What hooks can I use to detect a VM Shutdown event with Azure IaaS?

Tags: azure, iaas

I'm working on an automation tool whereby I need to trap events that are occurring within an Azure subscription.

Taking an Azure VM as an example - how can I trap a shutdown event for a single VM so that for example, a web service is called?

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Scheduled Events](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/get-started-with-scheduled-events/) (in Preview at time of post) is your best bet.  This is built upon the [Azure Instance Metadata Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-instancemetadataservice-overview) (also in Preview at time of post) which surfaces historic and up-coming information from within the VM, allowing you to proactively react to events.

To my knowledge, there's no way to monitor for events such as this from outside the VM, however [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-scheduled-events) article provides some great code examples which could be run from within the VM that you could use to trigger an alert/action outside the VM if you needed to.